# Where is the well located?

Tags: ramble-planet

SLATE and FILTER are found in a well on the surface... Where is it?

I would have guessed in the desert somewhere, but I've combed every bit of the surface looking for it. Is the well tucked away hidden somewhere, or did I not recognize it as interactive?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 wells and they are close to each other. Both are found north of the Grove area and just west of the building with the 2 recruitable robots in it. They are on an island with a house surrounded by a moat. Unless you already searched it all, there should be some junk floating in the moat.

To reach the wells, walk into the house with the floating man in it. The north wall of the house disintegrates if you touch a weak spot. The 2 wells are outside of the house. One has a level 0 monster in it, the other has a level 3 monster in it. The 2 items you seek are in the bottom of those wells.

Happy hunting!